# IE css - last table row to expand to fill remaining height

Tags: css, html-table, cross-browser, row

Given HTML like the following, how can I get the last row to take up the remaining height, and have the n-1 first rows to take up just as much height as they need?

This seems to work as is in Chrome, but not in Firefox2 or IE6/7/8.

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="5"><div style="border: 1px solid #cdcdcd; width: 100px; height: 300px;"/></td>
    <td/>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>one</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>two</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>three</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>full</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

So, the idea is that the last row, with "full" in it, should be really tall, and the other rows, "one", "two" and "three" should be as small as possible.

I've tried stuff like putting exact heights on the rows, say "<tr style="height:20px;"> and I've tried 100% height on the last row, no luck so far!

**Update:**

This layout is going to be used for varying types of content, and the intention is for the table to size itself to the content.  Sometimes the div will be tall, then its height determines the table's height, but othertimes the div is short, then the rows (one, two, three) determine the table's height.

Comment: I don't have a quick answer for you, but I think that you will have to use javascript to implement this feature.

Comment: I'm hoping there is a non javascript solution :)

Comment: Agreed, after some more testing I'm withdrawing my previous answer as it doesn't solve the height issue at all. Sorry about that. :-/

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html><body>
<table border=1>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="2"><div style="border: 1px solid #cdcdcd; width: 100px; height: 300px;"/></td>
    <td valign=top style="padding:0px;">
        <table height=1>
            <tr>
                <td>one</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
                <td>two</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
                <td>three</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
    <td valign=top>full<br><br><br>more full</td>
  </tr>
        </table>
  </td>
  </tr>
</table>
</body></html>
```

**Updatedx3, works in ie6/ff**

Comment: 1. I've got a lot invested in a table based layout, so if possible I need to stick with tables.  2.  I imagine you'll disagree with me, but divs really suck at tabular layouts.

Comment: I don't think setting "height: 100%;" will work on the table, I want the table to be as tall as it needs to be, not as tall as its container.

Comment: Well by definition "As tall as it needs to be" is the fixed height but with the "Full" one collapsed, perhaps you want to set `min-height: ##%` on the last element instead?

Comment: The table's height should be the height of its content - the fixed height content (the div) might be the tallest, or it could be really short, then the rows (one, two, three) might be the tallest.

Comment: ok, updated the html, should work now, the `height: 1px;` doesn't matter, it will expand if the contents deem neccesary

Comment: I tried your HTML, but with "height: 15px;", and it doesn't work for me, it renders the same as the original HTML for me (in IE6/7/8), (once I fixed rowspan=4 to be 5)

Comment: hmm, not working at all for me. I am using: <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

Comment: I removed the doctype, the HTML here renders the same as my original HTML (for me, on IE6/7/8)

Comment: It works for me, are you perhaps on IE? (Pain in the ass) if you are on firefox, the firebug plugin is very good for diagnosing these problems, but with a blank html page with that content, it works here...

Comment: Heh, the *question* is about getting this to work on IE.  I've mentioned i"m on IE twice in comments to you :)

Comment: I'm not really *on* ie, I use chrome myself, but I'm testing in all browsers, and IE/FF2 are the ones causing issues.

Comment: Oh, sorry, damn I'm on linux here... you could set the height on the table to the height of the div, then set the height of the last row to be very high, then if it needs more space it should just take it, but this is theoretical as I have no IE installed here :)

Comment: I'm on linux too. running XP in a virtual machine.  I can't set the height of the table to the div, because sometimes I have short divs and then the table's height is determined by the rows (one, two, three)

Comment: Ok, I found an old IE6 wineprefix, I'm trying some stuff. Looks to me like you will need to use divs (There are display properties which mimic tables) to get this right.

Ok, option one, set <tr height=200> on the last one... not a happy thought...

Comment: There might be a potential here if we put the first three in their own table inside that cell...

Comment: Yeah I did think of that - but in the *real* layout I'm using this repeating this layout many times in a big table.  This layout represents a product (the div is really an img, and the one,two,three are specs), and I want the specs to line up from product to product.

Comment: If that's all, `valign=top` on the td containing the second table will do the trick... lemee update the answer

Comment: I think putting one,two,three in their own table will fix the layout, but won't support the bigger picture layout I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: **Updated** the code, try this out, it looks great in FF (with height attribute) but something in IE is keeping the height up...

Answer (score 0):

If javascript is ok, you could use jQuery and find the top position of the last row and the position of the bottom of the window or element. The difference should be set as the height of the last row.

I didn't do any code yet, because I wasn't sure if you were looking for a table inside of an object or to have it fill to the bottom of the window. I can do that for you if you'd like with some more detail.

Comment: No javascript thanks.  The intention is the table's height should be the height of its content.